# How to resend same newsletter from Simplenews?

Tags: commerce, emails

I'm using simplenews module in Drupal 7. Also I have working mailing system as well as Cron system. I want to resend the newsletter that has been sent previously. I don't want to edit the database every time for resending. I want to send newsletter using user interface itself.

I tried editing **simplenews.module** and **simplenews.admin.inc** files.

I edited **simplenews.module**

```
/**
* NEWSLETTER SENT STATUS
*/
define('SIMPLENEWS_STATUS_SEND_NOT', 0);
define('SIMPLENEWS_STATUS_SEND_PENDING', 1);
define('SIMPLENEWS_STATUS_SEND_READY', 0);
define('SIMPLENEWS_STATUS_SEND_PUBLISH', 3);
```

But as I edited for SIMPLENEWS_STATUS_SEND_READY, it started giving me notice in the admin panel stating:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 2 theme_simplenews_status() (/home/#####/public_html/#######/sites/all/modules/simplenews/includes/simplenews.admin.inc file row number　1776 ).

But I couldn't edit **simplenews.admin.inc** file. And in the newsletter sending option it shows following message but don't send message when I run Cron:

> This newsletter is pending

Please help if someone has faced the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps easier to clone and then resend the newsletter node with the [node_clone](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_clone) module.

```
The clone module allows users to make a copy of an existing item of site content (a node) and then edit that copy.
```

Comment: Ok. I'll try using the mentioned module.

Comment: Though this is not the right method that I want, I'll use this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a old issue but it may help anybody looking for quick solution. I was looking for the same functionality and end up with [Simplenews Status Reset](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews_status_reset) module..(posted on August 1, 2015) it's allows to reset the sent status of an already send node/news so that you can send it again.